# MVC RegularExpressionAttribute. Testing for repeated characters regexp does not work

Tags: c#, regex, model-view-controller, validation

I need to check that the field contains duplicate characters (more than three). I use a regular expression in an RegularExpressionAttribute, but it does not work.
For example,

- pattern: ([a-zA-Z])\1{2}
- input: abcdddf
- result: no match!

in the source code attribute has the following code:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    this.SetupRegex();
    string str = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        return true;
    }
    Match match = this.Regex.Match(str);
    return ((match.Success && (match.Index == 0)) && (match.Length == str.Length));
}
```

If instead of a string

```
return ((match.Success && (match.Index == 0)) && (match.Length == str.Length));
```

was only

```
return match.Success;
```

then the problem would be solved.
is there any idea how to get around this limitation without implementing a custom RegularExpressionAttribute? May itself be a regular expression to others?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regex:

```
(?=.*([a-zA-Z])\1{2}).*
```

The regex above matches the whole string (`.*`) but only if there are duplicate characters somewhere in the string (`(?=.*([a-zA-Z])`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only returning true if *the whole string* is made from exactly three identical characters. Due to your additional checks the validation behaves exactly like `^([a-zA-Z])\1{2}$`.

The

```
return match.Success;
```

approach is the one you should use.
Alternatively, you could also change your regex like this:

```
^.*([a-zA-Z])\1{2}.*$
```

Or if you want to match a string where there are other chars between the duplicate ones, you could use this pattern:

```
^.*([a-zA-Z])(.*\1){2}.*$
```

**Edit:**
As this question is about the regular expression for the `RegularExpressionAttribute`, a fact which I kind of overlooked while answering, the whole first paragraph can be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, the first expression that you wrote helped